# Material UI - Add "Today" button to <DatePicker />

Tags: material-ui

I need to have a "Today" button as in the image bellow, positioned somewhere in the red marked area (or somewhere else). I'm using material-ui v5 and I also tried to add prop **showTodayButton** but seems to do nothing...

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**2023 Update**

As mentioned by @Chaitanya, the `componentsProps` prop is deprecated (for v5), you should use `slotProps` instead.

**Original answer**

The bug mentioned by bhugo313 has been fixed by now but the documentation isn't very clear on how to add the "Today" button.

You need to provide an `actionBar` object via the `componentsProps`:

```js
import { DateTimePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DateTimePicker";

<DateTimePicker
    /* ... other props */
    componentsProps={{
       actionBar: { actions: ["clear", "today", "cancel", "accept"] },
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer... at least for v5.

Answer (score 5):

This is the [bug](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27922) of Material UI v5. There's [pending PR](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/28091) for this bug and it's not merged yet. Since v5 is still in RC stage, I think we should wait this PR to be merged.

`showTodayButton` prop works well on mobile date picker, but not on desktop date picker.

Answer (score 4):

The solution provided by @liiva will work as expected for v5. But you may get deprecated warning for `componentsProps`.

Instead to avoid the deprecation error, we can use `slotProps`.

The same property can be used for all the other date pickers as well (`DesktopDatePicker/MobileDatePicker`)

```
 <DatePicker slotProps={{
   actionBar: { actions: ["today"] },
}}/>
```